# Сохранение ссылок при перемещении каталога

Tags: unix

Есть папка в системе и есть ссылки(много) на эту папку. Как переместить папку на теряя ссылок?

Comment: Спасибо, оригинально, но мне не надо чтобы папка была на старом месте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переместите куда надо и сделайте символическую ссылку на новое имя под старым именем:

```
$ mv /старое/имя /новое/имя
$ ln -s /новое/имя /старое/имя
```